# Blackberry socket connection - application hangs on acceptAndOpen()

Tags: sockets, blackberry, connection, inputstream

There is code,written not by me for Blackberry:

```
public class ServerThread extends Thread {
    ...
        String url = "socket://:12345;deviceside=true;interface=wifi";
        ServerSocketConnection connect = (ServerSocketConnection) Connector.open(url);

        SocketConnection sc = (SocketConnection) connect.acceptAndOpen();
        InputStream input = sc.openInputStream();
    ...
```

I started Blackberry simulator and debugged this code,discovered, that `connect` variable is OK,but aplication **hangs** on `connect.acceptAndOpen()` call.

I'm new in Blackberry and socket.
As I assume,that simulator expects some input from `localhost`,but don't get it.

If it is,how can I provide such input?
Should I start additionally some process on `localhost`?

**EDITED:**

```
public class MyApp extends UiApplication
{
...
    public MyApp()
    {        
        new ServerThread().start();        
        // Push a screen onto the UI stack for rendering.
        pushScreen(new MyScreen());        
    }
...
```

Comment: Localhost is the device, you need to enter a valid IP address. You also need this code in another thread.

Comment: this `final String localAddress = connect.getLocalAddress();` gives me my real valid IP of my PC,where the simulator was ran.I checked it already.

Comment: Michael,sorry,I don't quite undesrtand.Do you mean,that I should specify IP implicitely somehow?thanks

Comment: Looks like I should erform some push,as I undertand from BB forums.I will appreciate any help about this.Can't get how to do it.

Comment: getLocalAddress will give the IP of the device, you need the IP you want to connect to, the server.

Comment: The code I mentioned in post is for testing BB UI - clicking on field etc.So I have one application - this testing code and `MyScreen` on UI,which launched on simulator.So it is the server,isn't it?I've edited post.Could you,please,look at it.

Comment: The thread will be locked, it's waiting for a connection from a client.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9436/discussion-between-michael-b-and-sergionni)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to open a direct TCP connection over Wi-Fi on simulator.

You can't connect to localhost from simulator because it uses a MDS simulator as proxy for every connection, which in turn prevents you from accessing localhost. (I'm assuming for "localhost" you meant a server socket running on your development workstation)

So I'd recommend you to remove the wi-fi suffix from URL when testing on simulator, and connect to your workstation server using its true IP address on the workstation LAN. You can use the ";interface=wifi" suffix in simulator only after configuring WLAN in simulator, but this simulated network is pretty useless since you can't place any real device inside.

Comment: it's OK with `wifi` or `edge` parameters.I checked it already.The problem is other.I've already discovered.Due to bad understanding of sockets I made dummy mistake,when didn't initialize client.For my case it may simply be call `localhost:12345` from browser URL.Then acceptAndOpen() worked OK.